# deprecated global warning after importing createDrawerNavigator from react-navigation v4

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo, react-navigation

Your project is accessing the following APls from a
deprecated global rather than a module import: Constants
(expo-constants).
The global"_expo" and "Expo" objects will be removed
in SDK 41. Learn more about how to fix this warning:
https://expo.fyi/deprecated-globals

Answer (score -1):

Actually react-navigation version v4 is accessing global "_expo" and "Expo" variables inside the code as of and now expo is giving warning. Now this warning coming from any library where they are using this globals now if this warning is coming from 3rd party libraries then you can ignore this warning by by importing the LogBox `import { LogBox } from 'react-native';`
and then adding the code `LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Your project is accessing the following APIs']);`
You can read more on this [Expo deprecated globals](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/deprecated-globals.md)